# Skip source field in model mapping

Tags: java, modelmapper

Am trying to map a entity object into a DTO, The entity has a one to many relationship which I dont want to map. Additionally this is causing db calls I want to avoid (Lazy loaded)

Is there a way to skip a source field in mapping?

Tried using conditional mapper but this expects a destination set function

Comment: For your case (manual mapping) you can easily skip this field, but if you use some mapping framework (e.g. orika, dozer) - please provide information about it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I use modelmapper http://modelmapper.org/